# Code throws TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, typeerror

The code is an implementation of a localization algorithm :

```
colors = [['red', 'green', 'green', 'red' , 'red'],
          ['red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'red'],
          ['red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red'],
          ['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red']]


motions = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]]

p_move = 0.8

def show(p):
    for i in range(len(p)):
        print p[i]

p = []
sum=0
for i in range(len(colors)):
    for j in range(len(colors[i])):
        sum+=1

p=[[1.0/sum for j in range(len(colors[i]))] for i in range(len(colors))]

def move(lst,u=[]):
    q=[]
    if (u[0]!=0) :
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            new=[]
            for j in range(len(lst[i])):
                val=lst[j-u][i]*p_move
                new.append(val)
            q.append(new)



    elif (u[1]!=0) :
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            new=[]
            for j in range(len(lst[i])):
                val=lst[i][j-u]*p_move
                new.append(val)
            q.append(new)

    return q

a=[[0 for i in range(len(colors[j]))] for j in range(len(colors))]

for i in range(len(motions)):
    a=move(p,motions[i])   


show(p)
```

The above code throws the `TypeError` specified in the question for the following statement:

```
val=lst[i][j-u]*p_move
```

Please tell me why this is happening. I am a novice in python and can't see a reason why the compiler should throw this error.
Also, I am trying to change values in a column and a row according to the values in the lists present in the `motions` list. Is the manner in which I am trying to achieve this correct?

**EDIT**

Many have asked for the purpose of this code. I will iterate what I mentioned in the comments section of the question  : it is a part of a code meant to implement a localization algorithm . This part of the code is used to calculate the probability of movement. The probability of a success of a movement to the desired cell is p_move = 0.8. The previous probability of a given cell is multiplied by this value if the device is commanded to move to that cell.

However the sample output, requested for by one of the commentators requires the inclusion of the other part of my code which will require further explanation and muddle the purpose further.

Comment: Because `u` is a list, and `j` is an integer, you're passing lists to your functions.

Comment: Damn!How stupid of me..@sukrit why didn't you post this as answer?

Comment: Because, I can't answer your second question atm. :P

Comment: You do an awful lot of looping over `range()`; just loop ever the lists themselves instead. `for i in range(len(lst)):` can be replaced with `for elem in lst:`, replacing all `lst[i]` references with `elem` in the loop.

Comment: To me, it is unclear what you are trying to do with your code. Care to give a sample expected output in your question?

Comment: Your `sum` variable masks the `sum()` built-in function, which you could use to calculate that value. `sum(len(row) for row in colors)` returns the total number of colors you have in the nested list.

Comment: @Martijn Peters: I've rendered that as `total = sum(len(c) for c in colors)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do I use `elem` to change the values in a column? And as for the purpose of the code, it is a part of the code meant to implement the localization algorithm . This part of the code is used to calculate the probability of movement.  The probability of a success of a movement to the desired cell is `p_move = 0.8`. The previous probability of a given cell is multiplied by this value if the device is commanded to move to that cell.

Comment: See the posted answer; generate indices with `enumerate()` instead. Another method is to use a list comprehension to generate a replacement list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a speculative improvement on your code. Like so many others, I don't see what you are trying to do. Also, the setting of index inside `move` needs elaboration. Presumably it is some value from `u`.

```
from pprint import pprint

colors = [
    ['red', 'green', 'green', 'red' , 'red'],
    ['red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'red'],
    ['red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red'],
    ['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red']
]

motions = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]]

p_move = 0.8

def move(lst, u):
    q = []
    if u[0] != 0:
        index = u[0]
        for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
            q.append([lst[j-index][i] * p_move] for j in range(len(elem)))
    elif u[1] != 0:
        index = u[1]
        for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
            q.append([lst[i][j-index] * p_move] for j in range(len(elem)))
    return q

def main():
    total = sum(len(c) for c in colors)
    p = [[1.0 / total] * len(c) for c in colors]
    a = [[0] * len(c) for c in colors]
    for m in motions:
        a = move(p, m)
    pprint(p)

main()
```

Comment: what is the statement: `for i, elem in enumerate(lst) doing?

Comment: Elaborating on `index` , it is supposed to be u[0] and u[1] for respective conditions.

Comment: `enumerate` gives you an index and an element from a list. See here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html

Comment: Updated to set index based on `u`. Still no clarity on what the computation means. OTOH, the code matches the original with a comparable edit, so that is good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I quite understand what you are trying to do. @hughdbrown has provided many improvements taking the code as is but I can't tell what you are trying to achieve with the code so I'm wondering if you are looking for something different.
If you are looking to change a specific value based on the movements in the motions list, then would something as simple as:

```
a = [[0]*len(c) for c in colors]
index = [sum(x) for x in zip(*motions)]
a[index[0]][index[1]] = p[index[0]][index[1]] * p_move
```

or if you are looking to change every value along the movements then a generator function could work:

```
def move(motions):
    index0, index1 = 0, 0
    for m in motions:
        index0 += m[0]
        index1 += m[1]
        yield (index0,index1)

motions = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]]
a = [[0]*len(c) for c in colors]

for row,col in move(motions):
    a[row][col] = p[row][col]*p_move

show(motions)
show(p)
show(a)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
[0, 1]

[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]

[0.04, 0.04, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0.04, 0.04, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```